# Catch nil pointer dereference in Struct properties

Tags: go

I am trying to find the best way to catch `nil pointer dereference` when trying to access the property of the struct that is an address to another type.

Assume we have these structs (The code is for demo only. My intention is to convey a point)

```
type Location struct {
  coordinates *Coordinates
}

type Coordinates struct {
  lat *Latitude
  lon *Longitude
}

type Latitude struct {
  lat float64
}

type Longitude struct {
  lon float64
}
```

Initialising empty Location and accessing `loc.coordinates.lat` obviously yields an error as expected

```
loc := Location{}
fmt.Println(loc.coordinates.lat) // runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

To solve this problem I can do

```
if loc.coordinates != nil {
  fmt.Println(loc.coordinates.lat)
}
```

But in this case, if I want to print out `lat` property of `Latitude` I must add another `if` statement as follows

```
 if loc.coordinates != nil {
    if(loc.coordinates.lat != nil){
          fmt.Println(loc.coordinates.lat.lat)
    }
  }
```

I am wondering if there is any other way of handling this situation without checking if every address is not equal to `nil`. Is there anything like `val, ok := someMap["foo"]` in Go for structs?

Comment: One approach is to define fields as values instead of pointers: `coordinates Coordinates`,    `lat Latitude`, 
  `lon Longitude`

Comment: The code is for demonstration only. I just wanted to convey the point ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you define pointer types, you have to deal with them being possibly nil. One way to do it is to check every access. Another way is using getters that can deal with nil receivers:

```
func (c *Coordinates) GetLat() (Latitude,bool) {
  if c==nil {
    return Latitude{}, false
  }
  return c.lat,true
}

func (l *Location) GetCoordinates() *Coordinates {
   if l==nil {
      return nil
   }
   return l.coordinates
}

lat, ok:=l.GetCoordinates().GetLat()
if ok {
   // there is a valid lat
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, if l.GetCoordinates() returns nil then there will be a `nil pointer dereference error`.

Comment: No. GetLat handles nil receiver.

Comment: Oh I missed that part, thanks

Answer (score 2):

> I am w[o]ndering if there is any other way of handling this situation without checking if every address is not equal to nil.

No, there isn't. (Recovering from the generated panic is a bad practice, error prone and slow.)

> Is there anything like val, ok := someMap["foo"] in Go for structs?

No.

Comment: Thanks for your response, then I guess I have to check if an address is nil all the time.